# Numpy Convert String to Float when Possible

Tags: python, string, numpy, floating-point

Suppose I have a list

```
mix = numpy.array(['1.', '2.', 'a'])
```

How can I convert string to float when possible, so that I could get:

```
array([1., 2., 'a'])
```

I try to use `try / exception` with `astype()`, but it won't convert a single element.

Update:
In `csv` package, there is `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, I am wondering if `numpy` supports something similar.

Answer (score 5):

Didn't find a function to make it work, so I wrote something that works for you.

```
def myArrayConverter(arr):

    convertArr = []
    for s in arr.ravel():    
        try:
            value = float32(s)
        except ValueError:
            value = s

        convertArr.append(value)

    return array(convertArr,dtype=object).reshape(arr.shape)
```

Cheers

Comment: I tried a little bit to find a existing function to do that, but also could not.. your function is good, but not versatile. For instance, cannot handle two dimensional array. But give you up-vote for your prompt reply, man

Comment: Hi Vindicate, you did not specify you want something that works for more dimensions. Based on you example the answer given before would work perfectly for you. Without tweaking too much, I edited the solution and now it works for as many dimensions you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: it's great man, just hoping they could develop a method of conditional conversion.

Answer (score 2):

For arrays of mixed datatypes set `dtype=object`:

```
>>> mix = numpy.array(['1.', '2.', 'a'])
>>> mixed=[]
>>> for a in list(mix):
       try:
         mixed.append(float(a))
       except:
         mixed.append(a)

>>> mixed=numpy.array(mixed, dtype=object)
>>> mixed
array([1.0, 2.0, 'a'], dtype=object)
>>> type(mixed[0]),type(mixed[1]),type(mixed[2])
(<type 'float'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'numpy.string_'>)
```

Hope it hepls.

Answer (score 0):

One way that might work is checking if the string matches a number with a regex, and if so convert to float:

```
[float(x) if re.search('[0-9]*\.?[0-9]', x) else x for x in mix]
```